# Magento 2 : How to check multiple if config in layout?

Tags: magento2, layout, toplinks, system-config

Here is my code to add toplinks in my custom module

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" ifconfig="hello/general/enable" name="hello" >
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">hello</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">hello/index/index</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

I want to add toplinks only if both option are true.

How to add one more condition for `ifconfig="hello/general/toplinkenable"` with this block or is there any alternate solution to check both conditions to add toplinks?

Comment: Do you know about it how to implement.... 2 referenceBlock. For ex : 1st value select => 1st referenceBlock display ... 2nd value select => 2nd referenceBlock display .... 3rd value select => Both referenceBlock Display.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ifconfig` supports only one value.
In order to solve your problem, I suggest creating your own block that extends `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link` and add the conditions in the `_toHtml` method.

Something like this:

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;  

class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link
{
    public function _toHtml() 
    {
        if (
            !$this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag('hello/general/enable') || 
            !$this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag('hello/general/toplinkenable')
        ) {
            return '';
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

then include your block in the layout
Instead of this

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" ifconfig="hello/general/enable" name="hello" >
```

use this

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Link" name="hello" >
```

Comment: I have 3 referenceBlock and I need to display one by one based on condition from system config. What should I need to return?

Comment: Sorry 2 referenceBlock. For ex : 1st value select => 1st referenceBlock display ... 2nd value select => 2nd referenceBlock display .... 3rd value select => Both referenceBlock Display.

How can I do that?